# SQL Agent job hangs on packages with Execute Process Task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS package with the Execute Process Task, which runs 7zip exe to zip a file. This works fine when I run the SSIS. But when I run this SSIS from the SQL Agent it hangs. I assume this is something to do with the permission. I have given full control to Network Services and sqlsvc to the folder which has the zip exe and the folder it is extracting to. Still no luck. What should I do to make this SSIS run from th[image]e SQL agent.

Comment: If you create a sql agent job to perform an OS task and have it do all the same things the SSIS `Execute Process Task` is performing, do you encounter the same results?

Comment: Do the reports in the Integration Services Catalog show any errors or issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a proxy account which has administrator privilege and change the Job Step "Run As" property to the new proxy account instead of SQL Agent Service Account. I think the SQL Agent Service account doesnt have the access to run the process. You can also change the SQL Agent Serice Account group policies to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the WindowStyle property to Hidden - the SQL Server agent may be hanging when it tries to create a Windowed process.